# Escape JavaScript quotes in JSF with onclick events

Tags: javascript, jsf

```
onclick="window.open('/pages/PDocPreview.jsf?nid=#{pBeanDetail.id}&loadfirst=1&edit=true&fromPage=true&currentName=#{pBeanDetail.dName}&pId=#{pBeanDetail.user.id}', 'popupWindowName', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=1,toolbar=no,left =5, top=5, width=1100, height=800');"
```

Here, In `currentName=#{pBeanDetail.dName}` part I am facing issue when value contains `'`.

I have checked many possibilities but received error while page open.

1. with use of inner output text
2. With JSTL fn tag lib
3. combination of 1 & 2

Code Examples:(Not Working)

```
currentName=<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(pBeanDetail.dName,'\'', '\\'')}"></h:outputText>
```

```
currentName=#{fn:replace(pBeanDetail.dName,'\'', '\\'')}
```

*This question is different from similar question as I need to use EL expression with `fn` functionality in Javascript event

Comment: @BalusC: so Custom component is Solution for same. I have already same though BUT when you look at my question `"` and `'` are already used with `onclick` and with `window.open`. Now I am not able to use any quotes again. Please give solution of same if you have. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There are nowhere custom components. How exactly is the answer in abovelinked duplicate unclear? It precisely explains you how to escape JavaScript in Expression Language.

Comment: ohhh, not component its taglib, Now question is have you tried to use quotes inside the quotes? I am facing that kind of error here. Let me know if need more explanation. Mean you can not write quotes like:`"window.open('page.jsp?doc='v1'`')" here At v1 we will face issue.

Comment: Huh? So you haven't tried the answer at all? First do so and let me know if you still get the same error message.

Comment: let me try on that way

Comment: @Baluc: Thanks. It's silly mistake wile implementing